# How does Teleportation based Error Correction (TEC) detect and correct loss/erasure errors?

Tags: entanglement, measurement, error-correction, teleportation

I'm looking at papers like [Demonstration of teleportation-based error correction in the IBM quantum computer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.01692.pdf) (page) 10 and [Role of syndrome information on a one-way quantum repeater using teleportation-based error correction](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.00527.pdf) (pages 3 and 4 and figure 2).

In all these, they mention that a QND measurement enables the detection of error due to loss but I didn't quite understand how it is detected and how it is corrected.

I saw several other papers, that simply say that errors due to loss can be detected using TEC but I don't understand its working.